# Kafka broker on AWS - IP setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, apache-kafka, producer

I have installed Kafka software on EC2. My problem is connecting to broker from outside the AWS. It all work for me from inside.

So I can start the broker, and both kafka-console-producer and consumer works (from the same server). I have ports 2181 and 9092 open to the remote location, towards from where I would like to use producer. So from my development (local) machine .. If I do telnet  9092 - it  connects me. If i try to use kafka-console-producer i get this error.

`[2017-03-09 15:04:44,971] ERROR Error when sending message to topic topic2 with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for topic2-0: 1521 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time`

I tried all sorts of combination with  and  on server.properties file - with keys `listeners` and `advertised.listeners`.

I would really appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the fact that the public hostname/ip of AWS machines cannot be used inside AWS. If so you need to fudge a bit. 2 things are needed:

- make sure you set  `advertised.listeners` to your *private* address
- in your local /etc/hosts, bind the local hostname of aws (eg. ip-10-0-0-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal) to the public IP

Then make sure you always only use the private hostname. This has been the root cause for me of many weird issues not giving any logs.